# scheb/2fa not detected/working on my project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5.4

**Bundle version**: 6.1
**Symfony version**: 5.4
**PHP version**: 8

I wish to add two-factor authentication to my project and I came across your solution which seems great to me. Initially, the installation seemed straightforward, but I must be missing something because my authentication still works with email and password as usual.

I follow the installation guide and this is a part of my security.yaml:

```yaml
main:
          lazy: true
          provider: app_user_provider
          remember_me:
              secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
              token_provider: 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\RememberMe\DoctrineTokenProvider'
              lifetime: 68400
          form_login:
              # "login" is the name of the login route
              login_path: login
              check_path: login
              enable_csrf: true
          logout:
              path: logout
              # where to redirect after logout
              target: login
          two_factor:
              auth_form_path: 2fa_login    # The route name you have used in the routes.yaml
              check_path: 2fa_login_check  # The route name you have used in the routes.yaml
```

My `SecurityController` look like this :

```php
#[Route('/login', name: 'login')]
    public function index(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if($this->isGranted('ROLE1') || $this->isGranted('ROLE2') ){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home_master_user');
        }
       elseif($this->isGranted('ROLE3') && $this->isGranted('ROLE')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
```

To be honest, I don't understand why it's not working even after following the various tutorials I've read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search it was just a problem in the security.yaml :

```
main:
        two_factor:
            auth_form_path: 2fa_login    # The route name you have used in the routes.yaml
            check_path: 2fa_login_check  # The route name you have used in the routes.yaml
            provider: app_user_provider
            enable_csrf: true
```

I put the provider in two factor and now it works